# Front end not logged in when I am logged in at the back end EE6.2.5

Tags: control-panel, comments, simple-search, settings

When I am logged in as super admin the front end is not recognising this, and so I am unable to post comments, use the search engine, among other things. Is it likely that there is something wrong in my backend settings, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Check in your EE security & privacy settings to see if the CP session and website session settings are the same: for the two to operate from the same login you'll need the settings of both to be set to "cookie only".

HTH

Comment: Yes - that works. Thank you so much.